# Rails: get all assets belonging to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a Brand model which has a lot of assets:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :logo1, :logo2, :colour1, :colour2, :prices_attributes

  has_attached_file :logo1
  has_attached_file :logo2

  has_many :users
  has_many :welcome_messages
  has_many :silos
  has_many :articles, :through => :silos
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :covers, :through => :libraries
  has_many :products
  has_many :prices, :through => :products, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices

end
```

Is there a quick way to get all the assets assigned to each brand? Or do I have to do something like `brand.articles.each do |article| ...` for each?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'assets'?

Comment: Like all `:users, :welcome_messages...`, etc.

Comment: Yep, there's no way to load all *assets*.  You have to go through each association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to eager load all the associations you can do the following:

```
def self.all_associations
  includes(:users, :articles, :prices, :products) #and any other association
end
```

Then you can run `Brand.all_associations` or `Brand.all_associations.find(1)`

As jvnill wrote this will result in n database queries, so in the above example 5 database queries.

Comment: Just a correction that this doesn't result to 1 database query.  It results to n database queries where n is the number of tables affected by the query.  This only eager loads the associations so no queries are run after the object is loaded.

Comment: that's true, I'll reword it

Comment: That does raise an interesting issue though: if I was to list those results in a view, a `user` may have a `:name` but an `article` may have a `:title`. How would I iterate over them?

Comment: You would still need to iterate over them separately, your question wasn't too clear but I thought the above would help.

Answer (score 1):

Further to mind.blank's solution, if you don't want to repeat yourself, you can simplify things a step further:

```
def self.all_associations
  includes *reflect_on_all_associations.collect(&:name)
end
```